# Adding a widget under an 'Add to Cart' button through a PHP snippet

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Despite that my PHP knowledge is very scarce I've managed to add some elements under the add-to-cart button in my installation of Woocommerce with the function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'astra_add_woocommerce_payments', 97 ); 
function astra_add_woocommerce_payments()
```

I'd like to also add a [small currency converter calculator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/currency-converter-calculator/) widget using the same function, if possible, but my Google-fu hasn't returned useful results. Do I need to access the source code of the plugin? is there an easy way to do it? where do I start?

Hope to improve my programming skills bit by bit with your help guys. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin for the converter supports shortcodes, so [this is a good starting point](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).
Everything should be as simple as using this code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'astra_add_woocommerce_payments', 97 ); 
function astra_add_woocommerce_payments(){
  echo do_shortcode( '[currency_converter_calculator lg=”en” tz=”0″ fm=”EUR” to=”USD” st=”info” bg=”FFFFFF”][/currency_converter_calculator]' );
}
```

You probably want to wrap the shortcode result inside a `div` or something to size it properly for your add to cart area.

You can also take the "register sidebar" road and create a proper sidebar/widget area so you can control it from the backend, in that case take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes).